# Média entre vetores dentro de funções (python)

Tags: python, array, funções, lista

Boa tarde pessoal, tenho o seguinte código:

```
def Ler_vetor():
VET= []*10
for i in range(0,10):
    VET.append(int(input('Digite um número: ')))
return VET

def Escreva_vetor(VET):
print('Dentro do vetor (permutado) tem:',VET)

def Somar_vetor(VET):
pares = []
for i in range (0,10):
    if VET[i] % 2 == 0:
        pares.append(VET[i])
soma = sum(pares)
print('A soma dos pares é: ',soma)
return pares

def Contar_vetor(VET):
contador = 0
for i in range (0,10):
    if VET[i] % 2 == 0:
        contador += 1
print('Possui dentro do vetor: {} pares'.format(contador))
return contador

def Trocar_vetor(VET):
for i in range(0,10,2):
    aux = VET[i]
    VET[i] = VET[i+1]
    VET[i+1] = aux

print('----- Vetor A : -----')
vetA = Ler_vetor()
Somar_vetor(vetA)
Contar_vetor(vetA)
Trocar_vetor(vetA)
Escreva_vetor(vetA)
```

Basicamente ele lê um vetor de 10 posições, soma todos os pares, conta quantos pares tem, troca os impares de posição jogando para frente e escreve.
essa parte para o que preciso está OK.
 
Agora precisaria fazer a média aritmética dos números pares dentro do vetor e não consigo de maneira nenhuma, sendo que essa média não pode ser através de função e sim no programa principal, abaixo do Escreva_vetor(vetA).
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Aqui um exemplo da saída:

```
----- Vetor A : -----
Digite um número: 1
Digite um número: 2
Digite um número: 3
Digite um número: 4
Digite um número: 5
Digite um número: 6
Digite um número: 7
Digite um número: 8
Digite um número: 9
Digite um número: 10
A soma dos pares é:  30
Possui dentro do vetor: 5 pares
Dentro do vetor (permutado) tem: [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue a solução conforme o enunciado:

```
def Ler():
    entrada = input('Entre com o vetor: ')
    return [ int(n) for n in entrada.split(",") ]

def Somar(v):
    return sum(v)

def Contar(v):
    return len(v)

def Pares(v):
    return [ n for n in v if not n % 2 ]

def Somar_Pares(v):
    return Somar(Pares(v))

def Contar_Pares(v):
    return Contar(Pares(v))

def Trocar(v):
    vaux = v[:]
    for i in range( 0, len(vaux) - 1, 2 ):
        vaux[i], vaux[i + 1] = vaux[ i + 1 ], vaux[i]
    return vaux

# 1 - Leia dois vetores de numeros inteiros de 10 posicoes
v1 = Ler()
v2 = Ler()

# 2 - Imprima os dois vetores lidos
print("Vetor A: {}".format(v1))
print("Vetor B: {}".format(v2))

# 3 -  Calcule a soma dos numeros pares contidos em cada vetor.
print("Soma dos Numeros Pares do Vetor A: {}".format(Somar_Pares(v1)))
print("Soma dos Numeros Pares do Vetor B: {}".format(Somar_Pares(v2)))

# 4 - Conte quantos valores pares existem em cada vetor
print("Qtd. de Numeros Pares no Vetor A: {}".format(Contar_Pares(v1)))
print("Qtd. de Numeros Pares no Vetor B: {}".format(Contar_Pares(v2)))

# 5 - Para cada vetor lido no item a troque os elementos de ordem impar
#     com os de ordem par imediatamente seguinte para cada vetor
vtr1 = Trocar(v1)
vtr2 = Trocar(v2)

# 6 - Imprima os dois vetores apos as trocas.
print("Vetor A Trocado: {}".format(vtr1))
print("Vetor B Trocado: {}".format(vtr2))

# 7 - No programa principal calcule a media aritmetica dos numeros pares
#     contidos nos vetores
pares1 = [ n for n in v1 if not n % 2 ]
pares2 = [ n for n in v2 if not n % 2 ]

media1 = sum(pares1) / float(len(pares1))
media2 = sum(pares2) / float(len(pares2))

print("Media Vetor A: {}".format(media1))
print("Media Vetor B: {}".format(media2))

# Fim #
```

Saída:

```
Entre com o vetor: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Entre com o vetor: 1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,8
Vetor A: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Vetor B: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8]
Soma dos Numeros Pares do Vetor A: 30
Soma dos Numeros Pares do Vetor B: 28
Qtd. de Numeros Pares no Vetor A: 5
Qtd. de Numeros Pares no Vetor B: 5
Vetor A Trocado: [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9]
Vetor B Trocado: [3, 1, 7, 5, 2, 9, 6, 4, 8, 8]
Media Vetor A: 6.0
Media Vetor B: 5.6
```

Comment: Opa amigo obrigado pela resposta, mas sou "obrigado" a fazer o resto com funções:
Leia dois vetores de números inteiros de 10 posições;
Imprima os dois vetores lidos;
Calcule a soma dos números pares contidos em cada vetor.
Conte quantos valores pares existem em cada vetor
Para cada vetor lido no item a troque os elementos de ordem ímpar com os de ordem par imediatamente seguinte para cada vetor
Imprima os dois vetores após as trocas.
Os itens anteriores devem ser desenvolvidos por meio de funções.No
programa principal calcule a média aritmética dos números pares contidos nos
vetores

Comment: @GustavoSantos: Feito!

Comment: Opa muito obrigado, entretanto me retornou esse erro:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
Vetor A: [5]
Vetor B: [8]
  File "C:/Users/Dovah/PycharmProjects/trabalhoPROG/Trabalho2.py", line 56, in <module>
Soma dos Numeros Pares do Vetor A: 0
    media1 = sum(pares1) / float(len(pares1))
Soma dos Numeros Pares do Vetor B: 8
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
Qtd. de Numeros Pares no Vetor A: 0
Qtd. de Numeros Pares no Vetor B: 1
Vetor A Trocado: [5]
Vetor B Trocado: [8]`

Comment: Repare que a entrada de dados é feita no formato: `n1, n2, n3, ...`

Comment: Falta de atenção minha, muito obrigado irei estudar o código e tentar refazer!!